# Auto-Update table cell based on user input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, cell, auto-update, onkeypress

I'm trying to auto-update a table cell based on changes in another table cell. The user has a firstname, lastname and username. The username consists of first initial + lastname. My current code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      function updateUsername(){
        var firstname = document.getElementById("tdFirstname").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("tdLastname").firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
        var username = document.getElementById("tdUsername").innerHTML = firstname + lastname;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id = 'confirm'>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <td id = 'tdFirstname'>
          <div onkeypress = 'updateUsername()' contentEditable>
            Johnny
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <td id = 'tdLastname'>
          <div onkeypress = 'updateUsername()' contentEditable>
            Sppleseed
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <td id = 'tdUsername'>
          JSPPLESEED
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code works (just putting the first and last names together, not worred about first initial yet), but its one letter behind. It doesn't update after a new character is entered, meaning if I update lastname to Appleseed (like it should be), just changing the one letter has no effect (username remains Sppleseed), but when a second key is pressed, it would change to Appleseed. Is it something wrong with my code? or did I miss something that I should have to update after the new character has been entered / deleted. This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`.

The keyup event is fired "when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed."

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html